# Complete this puzzle(the right way)

Tags: cipher, pattern, visual

A circle and squares.. Try to complete this picture(the white areas) and explain why!

[image]

Hint1a

> [image]

Hint1b

> °

Comment: I know comment section is not for a discussion, but folks do you have any idea about the puzzle?

Comment: I didn't got the puzzle:(

Comment: Just added a hint!

Comment: I think I understand your Hint 1b (I believe it relates to the parts of circles, not the squares, specifically, rot13(qrterrf, nf va natyrf)).  But my brain doesn't get me much further.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is an attempt at a partial solution.

> [image]

Some explanation:

> I extracted the "squares" from the circle which appear to be overlaid, and recreated the parts that are hidden based on what is visible.  The parts in orange are a guess (since they were hidden).
>  Then, treating the lines in the circle as overlapping colours, I decomposed the circle into the corresponding partial shapes, as suggested by the hint.
>  I then thought how this might be recombined with the squares and rectangles.
>      - If grey represents 1/4, then the shaped shaded mostly blue seems to have (about) 1/4 missing (white), so this might be assumed to be grey.

That is as far as my brain gets me.

Comment: I have one thought about what the rectangular shapes may mean, but it has given me an idea for another puzzle, so I won't share this just yet.

Comment: You're right about the shapes of grey, red, blue. And nice thinking/reasoning, but your answer is not correct. I'll add another hint later today!